# How to identify the cause of low Azure blob storage success rate

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Blob storage with relatively few blobs and relatively few reads. However, I only see a success rate of around 26%. It is a private container and all access is via the .NET SDK. How can I identify the reason for the low success rate? I see there are a ton of metrics available but I have no idea which to turn on. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you turned on storage analytics?

Comment: So I'm looking at this: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/. However, I don't know which of the metrics that I need to monitor to help figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Basically what you would want to do is enable Logging. Logs data would then go in $logs blob container and there you should get some more information about what calls are failing and for what reason.

Comment: Ah ok. So I found the $logs folder. Is there anything special I should do to be able to read the logs? It looks like a big jumble. Also, if you put your comment into an answer (and maybe include how to turn on logging) I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: It's just a CSV file that you can download and analyze. Schema of the log file can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343259.aspx. Let's first figure out the cause of the problem and then we will worry about marking the answer :).

Comment: Good call! So I'm getting a ton of 404's on stuff like this: https://***.blob.core.windows.net:443/mam/***/4510150a3f584458a7fa8ca0ce5456a3/***/***_IN_1/MACommanda.xml and https://***.blob.core.windows.net:443/mam/MACommanda.xml. Using *** in place of company-specific info....

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is for the diagnostics data. I would suggest you keep your diagnostics storage account separate from your main storage account.

Comment: Yes I agree. I would however like to identify why these files are not there if they are expected to be there....